# AngularJS Add additional items if ng-repeat less than x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following bit of code.  It basically displays a box with the first four images of resources linked to it.  What I need to do is add additional images if there are less than four.  I did some searching, but couldn't find anything.

```
<div class="collection_box" ng-repeat="i in collections">
    <div class="inner_collection_box">
        <div ng-repeat="r in i.resources || limitTo:4" class="collection_resource_image_div">
            <img class="collection_resource_image" src="/images/resource_images/{{ r.image }}" alt="{{ r.name }}" />
        </div>
        <strong>{{ i.name }}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To understand your question, if your i.resources object is containing images less than four, you want to add addinational images. Is that correct?

Comment: I guess that's a route I could go, add images on the server before it reaches the client.

Comment: What would these objects be populated with? Default values?

Comment: Yes, basically default images.

Comment: After inserting your images, you can check with ng-if to see if your image count is less than four and get addinational images from your controller. But i suggest you doing this control in your controller before sending data to your view, do it in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a filter to add extra images. So in your view it would look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="r in i.resources | limitTo:4 | addImages">...</div>
```

And your filter could look like this:

```
yourApp.filter('addImages', function () {
  return function ($input) {
    var defaultImgs = [ ... ]; // your list with default images

    if ($input.length < 4) {
      $input.concat(defaultImgs.slice(0, 4 - $input.length));
    }

    return $input;
});
```